# mysqlconnection not working in Django project M1 Mac

Tags: python, django, mysql-connector

im trying just to do `python manage.py migrate` in my project.

```
python --version
Python 3.8.2
```

My pip list in my venv:

```
Package     Version
----------- -------
asgiref     3.3.4
Django      3.2.4
mysqlclient 2.0.3
pip         21.1.3
pytz        2021.1
setuptools  41.2.0
sqlparse    0.4.1
wheel       0.36.2
```

My Django settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'msapi',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}
```

I've got an infinite error but most important:

- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/micenor/Documents/Proyectos/MarvelStudiosAPI/project/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/**init**.py", line 18, in 
  from . import _mysql
  ImportError: dlopen(/Users/micenor/Documents/Proyectos/MarvelStudiosAPI/project/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows
  Referenced from: /Users/micenor/Documents/Proyectos/MarvelStudiosAPI/project/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
  in /Users/micenor/Documents/Proyectos/MarvelStudiosAPI/project/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-darwin.so
- version_info, _mysql.version_info, _mysql.**file**
  NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined

Comment: did you install mysql in your pc ??

Comment: Yes, the first option here -> https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Comment: https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/django-connecting-to-mysql-on-an-m1-mac-throws-nameerror/6236/2